# Socket.io client not working with websocket server

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io, gorilla

I wrote a websocket server in go using https://github.com/gorilla/websocket.
On the client the front-end team want's to use Socket.io, and is not working.
With plain websockets everything works fine. I don't have a lot of knowledge about Socket.io, just what I read on internet, and I didn't found any decisive and recent answer.

Is there any possibility to make Socket.io to work with a normal websocket server?

Socket.IO Client Error: Timeout .
Socket.IO Client Code:

```
    var token = "valid_token";

    var socket = io(
        'ws://localhost:6060',
        {
            transports: ['websocket'],
            path: '/ws/dispatchers',
            query:  {
                token: token
            },
        }
    );

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log("------connect_error------");
        console.log(error);
    });

    socket.on('connect_timeout', (timeout) => {
        console.log("------timeout-----");
        console.log(timeout);
    });

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("---------connect---------");
    });
    socket.on('event', function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("---------disconnect---------")
    });
    socket.on('error', function(err){
        console.log("--------error------------");
        console.log(err)
    });

    socket.on('ping', () => {
        console.log("--------ping------------");

    });

    socket.on('pong', (latency) => {
        console.log("--------pong------------");
    });
```

Backend Error:  websocket: close 1005 (no status)
Backend code, is the same as:
https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

Comment: can you paste your code, and the error stack trace as well

Comment: SocketIO is a layer over other transports including WebSockets.  Use a SocketIO package on the server.  Depending on the features that the application is using, it may be better to drop SocketIO and use WebSockets directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Socket.io Documentation

> What Socket.IO is not Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation.
>   Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible,
>   it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace
>   and the packet id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is
>   why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a
>   Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect
>   to a WebSocket server either. Please see the protocol specification
>   here.